# Concurrent execution of metal compute kernels

Tags: macos, gpu, metal

Lets say, I have around 10 kernels, which I encode in an `MTLComputeCommandEncoder` and these 10 kernels, run on a set of data under consideration.

I have multiple sets of these data, let's say 5, and I want to execute these 10 kernels on all the separate sets of data. And NO! I cannot combine these data sets into a single data.

A naive approach would be to loop around all the data sets and execute all the 10 kernels on each data set, one after another.

What I'm looking for is a way that I can tell `Metal`, that these are separate data sets and they can be executed in parallel. That is, instead of encoding 10 kernels, 5 times sequently, I want to run all of them concurrently on the GPU.

CUDA provides `Streams` to achieve this behaviour. Is there anything similar the Metal provides?

I know there exists `MTLDispatchType`, setting it to `MTLDispatchTypeConcurrent`, would mean running my 10 kernels concurrently, but that is not the requirement.

Thanks!

Comment: "instead of encoding 10 kernels, 5 times sequently, I want to run all of them concurrently on the GPU" Why do you believe those two are in conflict. Encoding and running are two separate things. You encode commands to a command buffer. That doesn't run them (yet). When you commit the command buffer, it gets scheduled and then run. If you use `MTLDispatchTypeConcurrent`, then all of the commands in a buffer (regardless of in what order they were encoded) may execute concurrently (up to the capacity of the GPU).

Comment: @KenThomases When I say, they are run sequentially, in understanding the default `MTLDispatchType` is `MTLDispatchTypeSerial`., or is that wrong? `MTLDispatchTypeSerial` says all commands are executed sequentially, which means no concurrency?

Comment: Yes, `MTLDispatchTypeSerial` would make the commands run sequentially. So, just use `MTLDispatchTypeConcurrent`, instead. You say it doesn't meet your requirement, but it seems to me it does. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: @KenThomases Because it there are Kernels 1, 2, 3 .. 10, 11, 12... 20. I'm fine with 2 running concurrently with 11, 12, 13 ... 20. But, I want to ensure that 2 runs sequentially after 1, always, to ensure that 2 always receives updated data from 1.

Comment: Encode kernel 1 against the 5 data sets, encode a memory barrier on the output buffers, encode kernel 2 against the 5 data sets, encode a memory barrier, etc.

Comment: @KenThomases This would mean preprocessing CPU side, and collecting 5 states (1, 11, 21, 31, 41) and calling K1, that was something that I was trying to avoid.

Comment: But, I can probably use `MTLDispatchTypeConcurrent` and add memory barriers across 1,2,3..., to ensure that data they use is in sync. And also 11,12,13.. remain free for any order.

Comment: I think your question is under-specified, because I don't understand your requirements/constraints.